# Is there no timer that shows when the era ends?

Tags: reus

I am always confused when the era suddenly ends. Do I have to use an egg timer or is there a clock somewhere that I missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The timer is the blue bar running in the top left corner. If you hover over it, it also shows the exact time until your era ends.

[image]

When the time is up, you have 1 additional minute to do stuff, but within this timeframe all giants will go to sleep, so don't expect them to do anything. If that minute is over, the era ends.